# Synchronization Readers and Writers

Tags: operating-system

How to write to this questions? If honestly I don't understand meaning of this questions.
A) Write the solution of the Readers and Writers with precedence to Reader and comment the function of each semaphore. (Remember definition and initialization of variables and semaphores)
B) What does precedence to the readers mean?
What happens to the readers arriving when a writer is writing?
What happens when the writer ends its operation?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the constraints are the following:

1. Multiple readers can be reading at the same time.
2. Only one writer can write at one time.
3. If there are readers, there can be no writers.  If there is a writer, there can be no readers.

To solve this, you need to have a queue of waiting readers, a queue of waiting writers, count of current readers, and boolean variable to indicate if there is a writer.  Better yet, use condition variables to solve this if you have them.

Precedence to the readers means that writers only get to write if there are no current or waiting readers.

Readers arriving when there is a current writer get queued.

When a writer finishes, readers start if there are any waiting.  Otherwise the next writer starts.